# Not able to use function variables ? Error expression must have class type

Tags: c++

Hey i want to use the function wolves variable in the storyline and im trying to do this :

```
"\nYou awake on a beach to the sound of"<< Wolves().name; " starving and blood hungry," 
        "\nThere is a Rock on the ground.  You pick it up";
        inventory.push_back("Rock");
```

But Wolves().name;  there is an error as mentioned in the title.  Why cant i do this?

Here is the code for the function Wolves:

```
void Wolves()
{
    string name = "Wolves";
    int health = 20;
    hitPoints() +1;
}
```

Comment: It seems you need a class, not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access variables defined in a function from outside the function in C++, but you can change it to a class:

```
class Wolves {
  public:
    string name;
    // ...

    Wolves(); // Constructor
    //...
}
```

To access it you can use

```
Wolves wolve;
wolve.name = "whateverName"; // or set it in the constructor
cout << wolve.name << endl;
```

Comment: So i declare the variables in the class.  But when i try to give them a value.  There is errors......  I also cannot call a function.

Answer (score 1):

What you did in there is create local variables within the function.  Once the function exits, they no longer exist.  What you want to do is make a Wolves class and create public member variables to do what you want.  For an example,

```
class Wolves {
    public:
        string name;
        int health;

        Wolves(string name, int a);
}
```

Then on the main function,

```
Wolves w("Bob", 20);
cout << "The name is: " << w.name << endl;
```

Will output "The name is: Bob"

void functions don't really do anything unless you pass the value in by reference.  If you want to alter the object via void function, you should do something like

```
void Wolves(Wolves & wolfToChange)
{
    wolfToChange.name = "Bob";
}
```

and that will directly alter the object.

Answer (score 0):

You declared "name" as a local variable in a function called `Wolves()`, but the code that you were referring to expects the function `Wolves()` to return an object that has an accessible member `name`. That is why the compiler is complaining.

The way you wrote the code suggests that Wolves should be a class or struct, not a function.